# Aggregate functions in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a Crystal Report for which I only have access to edit the .rpt file, I can't edit the data source or the underlying wrapper so I can only make edits to the .rpt file.

Currently, I have data that I need to aggregate (Group by a few columns, with a list aggregate on a number column).

The input data is in XML format, I know the best way to achieve this grouping would be server side when the data is being populated, but I don't have the access to change that.

So I am wondering, is there a simple way to manipulate the input data before crystal starts printing the records?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is Crystal Report internal grouping (and optionally running totals) capability not enough for you?

Comment: Nah I have looked at it but this report is quite complex (and badly written in my opinion) - after a bit more reading i'm guessing the answer is no unless I completely rebuild the report.